# How to debug Sql Server Permission Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is quite lengthy and calls other stored procedures, as well as accesses tables directly.

The issue is that if I run the sp with dbo permissions it works.  However, when I connect via an app and give the connection a Sql Server user login with permission only for that stored procedure, then it fails.

As far as I understand it, if execute permission is granted to a stored procedure, then no other permissions are required.  Yet it fails to complete successfully. (It doesn't throw a specific permissions error, it just doesn't finish all the way and I can't debug it because to do so would require SysAdmin permissions which in itself would make the issue not manifest itself.)

So I am not sure where else to look to debug this.

Comment: I would consider a series of `PRINT` statements throughout the main SP.  One before and after each call to other SP's at a minimum.  Then connect to SSMS with the same credentials your app uses.  Run the SP and observer the print statements.  This may help you identify SP calls that are failing or never occur.

Comment: How's the debugging coming along?  Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this I hope this may help them as it helped me fix an issue like this.
I do not know how to debug this issue, however I do know that db_executor may not be enough permission as you can set up signatures for stored procedures as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver15
It is possible that the signature may need to be updated if someone has changed the associated store procedure or that additional permissions may need to get added to the user associated to the certificate user